# Creating packages from serialised items

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Does anyone have a code snippet or information for creating a Sitecore package from serialised .item files? Other requirements are that this needs to be accomplished without a Sitecore context or access to any of the Sitecore databases.

Comment: I've answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414482/is-it-possible-to-build-a-sitecore-data-package-from-command-line-or-outside-of

Comment: Thanks Sean. I've spent quote a lot of time looking at the `Sitecore.Install` namespace and have got the simplest possible example working without a Sitecore context or database connection. All of the more fully formed examples like `Sitecore.Rocks.Server.Packages.PackageBuilder` make API calls a that rely on a context database. If there's no examples already out there I'll persevere with building my own. Thanks again.

Comment: You may want to look into generating "Update Packages" rather than classic packages. They can be generated outside of a web context using the .item files. Something worth investigating is https://sitecorecourier.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Sitecore Courier](https://github.com/adoprog/Sitecore-Courier) Shared Source module. It simply compares two folders with serialized items and creates a diff package.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Liked the module so much that I've forked it on Github. Great work.