# Sitecore package generaton

Tags: .net, package, sitecore

I want to build Sitecore packages programmatically. Can you tell me what class I can use for this? Or tell me about any manuals about this?

In many manuals I can read only about create packages from Package Designer, but I don't need this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [Continous deployment with Powershell Console](http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2011/12/19/continuous-deployment-in-sitecore-with-powershell/).

You can also check `Sitecore.Install.PackageGenerator` class in the `Sitecore.Kernel`.

Some other ideas were linked [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414482/is-it-possible-to-build-a-sitecore-data-package-from-command-line-or-outside-of)

Answer (score 6):

In addition you should also take a look at [Sitecore Courier](http://sitecorecourier.codeplex.com/) and [Unicorn](https://github.com/kamsar/Unicorn).

Comment: Nice, hadn't realised he'd put something up

Comment: The Build.proj file in the Sitecore.Mvc.Contrib project has examples of how to generate update packages with Sitecore Courier and also how to automate the creation of Sitecore.Nuget enbabled packages.
ref. https://github.com/Sitecore-Community/Sitecore-Mvc-Contrib/blob/master/build/Build.proj